# AspectJ weaver gives me "incompatible return type applying to constructor-execution" when using @Around advice for constructor

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I'm attempting to inject a context for tracing into newly created Callable objects using @Around advice:

```
@Aspect
@Configurable
public class TracingAspect {

    @Around("execution(java.util.concurrent.Callable+.new(..))")
    public Callable wrapExecutor(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        Context context = Context.current();
        return context.wrap((Callable) pjp.proceed());
    }
}
```

When the weaver encounters a prospective joinpoint such as the anonymous Callable implementation in the following example:

```
public class Foo {

    private ExecutorService threadpool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    public Future<String> doStuffAsync() throws InterruptedException {

        return threadpool.submit(new Callable<Integer>() {

            @Override
            public Integer call() throws Exception {
                System.out.println(42);
                return 42;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I get the following error message from the Aspectj weaver:

`error at foo/bar/tracing/aspect/TracingAspect.java::0 incompatible return type applying to constructor-execution(void foo.bar.Foo$1.<init>(foo.bar.Foo))`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Questions: (1) Are you using Spring AOP (because I see a `@Configurable` annotation) or native AspectJ? (2) What does the `Context` class look like? I cannot run your code without it. I can already see that you are doing something wrong, but in order to elaborate and suggest an alternative, I need the questions above answered first.

Comment: 1) I am using native AspectJ w/ Loadtime Weaving 2) Context is part of the OpenTelemetry tracing library (https://javadoc.io/doc/io.opentelemetry/opentelemetry-context/1.0.1/io/opentelemetry/context/Context.html).

Comment: However, the details of Context are irrelevant because context,wrap(Callable callable) returns a callable object.  You could simply just return the constructed Callable via just (Callable) pjp.proceed() and the issue remains the same.

Comment: It would be better to let the people trying to help you decide what is relevant, because if you knew better then you probably could solve the problem by yourself. An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is always the best way to ask or answer a question. My answer below for instance is an MCVE. I just used compile-time instead of load-time weaving in order not to have to also share an _aop.xml_. I used OpenTelemetry in my example, which makes it much more relevant to you than any dummy example, I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you cannot replace a returned object from within the constructor `execution()`, because a constructor is not a normal method which could e.g. have a supertype or interface as return type. A constructor always returns exactly the object of the defined type, nothing else. This is not even an AspectJ limitation but a JVM limitation. With a byte code engineering library such as ASM you would have the same limitation.

So the best you can do in AspectJ is to replace the returned object in the constructor `call()`, but the object must also match the expected type. Unfortunately, OpenTelemetry returns a lambda instance which cannot be cast to the exact anonymous `Callable` subtype you have in your code. This means, there is nothing you can do here with that kind of code structure.

As a workaround, you can intercept calls to methods taking `Callable` instances, such as `ExecutorService.submit(Callable)`. You just need to make sure to capture all relevant ones. For example:

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public class Application {
  private ExecutorService threadpool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

  public Future<Integer> doStuffAsync() throws InterruptedException {
    return threadpool.submit(new Callable<Integer>() {
      @Override
      public Integer call() throws Exception {
        return 42;
      }
    });
  }

  public Future<Integer> doStuffLambdaAsync() throws InterruptedException {
    return threadpool.submit(() -> 77);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Application app = new Application();
    System.out.println("Future value = " + app.doStuffAsync().get());
    System.out.println("Future value (lambda) = " + app.doStuffLambdaAsync().get());
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import io.opentelemetry.context.Context;

@Aspect
public class TracingAspect {
  @Around("call(* java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService.submit(*)) && args(callable)")
  public Object wrapExecutor(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, Callable<?> callable) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(pjp);
    Context context = Context.current();
    return pjp.proceed(new Object[] { context.wrap(callable) });
  }
}
```

```
call(Future java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService.submit(Callable))
Future value = 42
call(Future java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService.submit(Callable))
Future value (lambda) = 77
```

Of course you could also filter the intercepted calls for callables with certain properties, if you are able to determine those with any accuracy, e.g. from which classes in which packages the calls were made etc.